# Why can't my serializer update name and bio at the same time? Validated data has only one key-value - bio

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update my user's profile and I stumbled into the issue: the bio is being updated, and the name is not. Using a debugger, it shows me that validated_data has only 'bio' key-value pair and returns `None` for the name, although my input into Browsable API is name+bio.

Debugger:

```
validated_data = {'bio': 'small update'}
new_name = validated_data.get('name')
new_name = None
```

What i pass into Browsable API:

```
{
    "name": "ttt_changed,
    "bio": "small update"
}
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):


    name = serializers.CharField(source='user.username',
                                         read_only=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True, required=False)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        new_name = validated_data.get('name')
        myuser = validated_data.get('user', instance.user)
        myuser_username = validated_data.get('name', myuser.username)
        myuser.save()

        instance.bio = validated_data.get('bio', profile.bio)
        instance.save()

        return instance, myuser

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('name', 'bio', 'image')
```

MyUser has One-to-One relationship with Profile model.

Thank you in advance for your replies, I can't wrap my head around why validated data doesn't contain the name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first problem is below:

```
name = serializers.CharField(source='user.username',read_only=True)
```

you did write read_only is True and this is because you can't see the name within your validated_data keys.

and the next problem is here:

```
myuser_username = validated_data.get('name', myuser.username)
```

underscore must not use between myuser and username,because username is an attribute of myuser object and you should use dote between them like below:

```
myuser.username = validated_data.get('name', myuser.username)
```

Comment: Thank you, Erfan, I totally overlooked ```read_only=True```, because it was needed for get method, and I was focused on update. Now it is working the way it should!